# How do you do a hard coded exclusion in a Spring JpaRepository interface method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic entity with a `code` property.  I want to select all of the rows where the property is not a specific value.  The value I'm testing against does not change, so I don't want to make it a param.

How do you exclude a hard coded expression via interface method naming?

EXAMPLE:
I want do exclude items where the code is 'FOO'. Am I able to just do:

```
List<MyEntity> findByCodeIsNotFOO();
```

My real world use case is more complex than this, but I wanted to know if something simple like this was even possible before I want down the more complex road.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured :-/   If you want to submit an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `@Query` annotation in order to achieve that.

`@Query("select me from MyEntity me where me.code != 'FOO'")`